# How to handle the chrome browser when it is directly opened from desktop application in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, winappdriver

I am using winappdriver for automation desktop application and selenium to handle web-browser. I have scenario in desktop application and need to enter the url in input box, it will open the default browser and url sending with dynamic id details.

Can you please guide how to handle the browser session in selenium when it is opened from desktop request

I have followed this link but no luck
https://learn-automation.com/how-to-execute-selenium-scripts-on-already-opened-browser/

Comment: You should elaborate on the "no luck" part. Show the code where you tried to take control of the existing browser using Selenium, what you tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.